# AngularJS Jquery Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-selectric

I am using Jquery Selectric on my page to render a select box in my angularJS app, so I decided to create a directive to render the element, below is the directive and how I use it.

**The Directive:**

```
angular.module('shoeRevamp.directives')
  .directive('selectric', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {countries: '='},
      controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        console.log($scope.countries);
      },
      link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        if( $("select").length) {
          $(el).selectric();
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

**How I use it (Jade/Pug):**

```
select(selectric ng-model='country' countries='countries' ng-options='country.name for country in countries track by country.symbol')
```

**The Problem**

When I load the page and try to open the select box it complains with the error below without displaying any of the countries:

**Error Message**

```
jquery.selectric.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of undefined
```

**Another Problem**

When I add `priority: -1000,` It displays the countries, but it looses its Selectric styles and behaviour.

I need help.

Comment: Is that Jade/Pug in your 'How I use it' section?

Comment: @HopefulLlama Yes, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Try to wrap the link function into a $timeout ddeclaration.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `if( $("select").length) {` and not `if( el.length) {`?

Comment: @ChristianBonato It still gives the same problem as  the `Another Problem` section of my question

Comment: @Malkus There is no particular reason

Comment: That's probably because the countries are coming from either a parent directive or controller. Did you try to $compile the element? Because from what I see your directive... calls itself???

Comment: @ChristianBonato I am not sure what that should look like, do you mind providing a solution as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So technically the problem you have is that when `selectric` is being initialized on the DOM you your `ng-options` hasn't populated the DOM yet so selectric has an empty list.

To fix this you need to load the data using the selectric `ajax` format to build the options and then inject them into the selectric dropdown.

## Javascript

```
.directive('selectric', function ($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {countries: '='},
      link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
          var myList = "";
          //Loop through the list of countries and build the options
          for(i = 0; i < scope.countries.length; i++) {
            myList = myList + "<option value='" + scope.countries[i].symbol + "'>" + scope.countries[i].name + "</option>";
          }
          //Start selectric and append option list
          el.append(myList).selectric();
      }
    };
  })
;
```

## HTML

```
<select ng-model='country' selectric countries='countries'></select>
```

*Couple things that are worth mentioning:*

- You cannot use ng-options natively with selectric, I had tried a hacky solution to put a timeout on using selectric but that created it's own issues
- Because you cannot use ng-options that also means you can't work with objects as the option value which is going to impose some limitations on your development.

Comment: I have some issue with this approach, I am not able to access the model unil I change a selected item, accessing it without changin selected item throws error  `angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'country' of undefined`

Comment: Are you sure there's not a Vanilla JS for doing what you'd like to achieve? JQuery plugins and Angular often spells $timeout()